# Images are not working in a iTunes affiliate Plugin in wordress (Shortcode)

Tags: wordpress, app-store-connect

I've created a blog related to Apple products and bought an iTunes items shortcode generator. So, all I've to do is put the app, music id in it and it will create a shortcode for me.
But, the problem is that the images/thumbnails are not working fine. They give me a question mark. So, how to fix that?
I've found the problem and created a video on it [Check it Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgz0t76axqb0r6z/is.mov?dl=0)

Please help me out to fix this issue [Check this out](https://www.ipadappsbuzz.com)

I'm using cloudflare flexible ssl on wordpress latest version.

Comment: Use https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/ - check this out: https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Purple3/v4/0d/7b/81/0d7b8132-e675-a897-3bde-aff34ba308d8/pr_source.png

Answer (score 2):

The problem is connected with SSL connection on is4.mzstatic.com

Starting the URL with a double slash inherits the current protocol.
That's why you should check https connection rather than http.

Check this out:
https://is4.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Purple3/v4/0d/7b/81/0d7b8132-e675-a897-3bde-aff34ba308d8/pr_source.png

**You should use this domain:
https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com**

https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Purple3/v4/0d/7b/81/0d7b8132-e675-a897-3bde-aff34ba308d8/pr_source.png

[image]

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=is4.mzstatic.com

> Certificate name mismatch
>
> We were able to retrieve a certificate for this site, but the domain
>   names listed in it do not match the domain name you requested us to
>   inspect. It's possible that:

Comment: How to fix it via .htaccess or modifying anything in the plugin or in cloudflare settings

Comment: No, I'm not usign this module.
I'm using this module :: http://codecanyon.net/item/itunes-shortcode-wordpress-plugin/8583750

Comment: It's hard to say without having an access to the module files but you can force using this domain or create custom rule in .htaccess.

Comment: You can search for it on your own. First of all I'd like to suggest asking here: http://codecanyon.net/item/itunes-shortcode-wordpress-plugin/8583750/comments

Comment: You can try to find is4.mzstatic.com domain in source files of the module and then replace it with ssl domain. Probably that's the easiest way for you. But if you disable ssl on your site it won't work until you replace it again.

Comment: Useful question connected with .htaccess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795924/htaccess-redirect-secondary-domain-to-primary-domain-with-ssl

Comment: should i modify the .htaccess as mentioned in the above suggestion ?

Comment: Read carefully and give it a try. But I still suggest contact with the author http://codecanyon.net/item/itunes-shortcode-wordpress-plugin/8583750/comments The last response was 13 hours ago.